# Email client supporting multiple accounts

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, email-client

I've been using Microsoft Outlook for a very long time, although one thing that has bugged me is how multiple email accounts are handled. As far as I can tell, there isn't a set and straightforward way of managing multiple accounts in one instance of outlook.

For example, when I create an email, saving it as a draft will by default dump it into the first personal folder that I have open, which in my current case, is not where I want it. I would like all trash, spam, drafts, contacts, etc. etc. to be handled on a PF by PF basis.

Now to my question: Is there a way to accomplish the task of email account "segregation" in Outlook (2007 is my current version), or is there another client that handles this in a more organized fashion?

Note: I don't use most of the features in outlook (I hardly even need special formatting for my messages), I generally just send and read mail, and get a few attachments, so leaving Outlook wouldn't be too much of a stretch for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mozilla's [Thunderbird](http://www.mozilla.org/thunderbird/) correctly handles individual Drafts folders on a per-account basis.

Comment: I just installed it, looking good so far. Thank you!